# How does solana handle multisig

Tags: multisig

I was looking into this and could not find an answer, only sites of products.Does solana handle multisig similar to ethereum via smart contract or closer to bitcoin?

Answer (score 1):

Solana multisig can sort of be categorized into two buckets...

##### Synchronous

If an instruction requires multiple signers that may or may not be the same account, so long as the person or application sending the transaction has access to all required signing keypairs, they can all partially sign the transaction as defined by the instruction. This would effectively be equivalent to `N` people turning a key to a door at the same time.

##### Asynchronous

This is where Solana's handling of multisig is almost entirely contract driven. Typically a single entity owned by a program will exist to orchestrate the signing/approvals of a group of people with a required threshold in order to execute or process a given instruction/transaction.

At their own discretion, each group member can approval an ephemeral representation of the proposed transaction, and once the threshold is met, the programmatic entity will have permission to process that proposal.

Comment: Thank you! Tried to upvote but not enough reputation